# When do pilots use NOTAMs?

Tags: flight-planning, notam, aeronautical-information

Usually, pilots will check NOTAMs during pre-flight prep. Are there some situations where they use them in a specific flight phase? If yes, in which case would it be useful?

Thank you

Comment: NOTAMs are a pre-flight planning aid. You plan around the NOTAMs published prior to takeoff. Depending on the nature of the NOTAMs, every phase of flight could be affected including the decision to fly at all. Plan properly, and you won’t have to use any further NOTAMs. In-flight planning will be done utilizing information gathered from the AFD, ATIS,  ATC and FSS. A single pilot inflight would lack the time to keep up with new NOTAMs without help. It has only been relatively recent that in flight NOTAMs were possible for your General Aviation pilot other than the aforementioned radio sources.

Answer (score 1):

Use or check? NOTAMs can give pilots of a wide range of information, so in terms of use each NOTAM is different. For example, they might tell the pilot that a frequency has changed - so that's something they may need to integrate into their flight at the relevant point.

Or, the classic, is that there are standing NOTAMs in the UK that overflying Ukraine and Syria aren't recommended. Not something most pilots need to worry about.

There is no expectation to check NOTAMs after departure, however.

Answer (score 1):

NOTAMs are a planning aid. Before flight you look at the NOTAMs that are applicable to your route, including diversion airfields, and extrapolate the information you need. A NOTAM may make you change your route, or take a note to use a different frequency or procedure. You may make a notation on a map, for example, or a hand-written note on your pad, presuming you use one.

Once flying it's unlikely you'd refer to NOTAM text, they are terse and can be cryptic, and often require plotting on a map. You may bring a printout of frequency changes I suppose, but that would be the extent of it. Some navigation systems can use NOTAM data to enrich a moving map, which is handy as a visual reference.